# Norm of orthogonal matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces, mathematical-physics

Can someone help me with this problem. I have no idea how to solve it!!

If A is a p×q matrix, U is a p×p orthogonal matrix, and Z is a q×q orthogonal matrix, prove that $||A||_2=||UAZ||_2$

Comment: I commented on an identical question an hour or so ago asking whether you (?) knew the definitions of orthogonal matrices and the two-norm. That's a good place to start, and it's good practice to put any work you've done towards solving the problem into your question (you could edit this one to include these). Otherwise, people assume you just want them to do your homework!

Comment: If B is orthogonal, then $\langle Bx,By\rangle  = \langle x, y\rangle  $

Comment: I did this ---> $|||UAZ||_2 \ = (UAZ)^T(UAZ)=Z^TA^TUTUAZ=Z^TA^TAZ$ now I don't know what to do. can I exchange the position of Z or $Z^T$ with A?!

Comment: This is already wrong - the two norm of a matrix is a positive real number, while $(UAZ)^T(UAZ)$ is a matrix. Please go back and revisit the definitions.

Answer (score 1):

$$\|UAZ\|_2^2=\rho(Z^*A^*U^*UAZ)=\rho(Z^*A^*AZ)=\rho(AZZ^*A^*)=\rho(AA^*)=\rho(A^*A)=\|A\|_2^2$$

Comment: Is $\rho$ the spectral radius ?

Comment: @matthiasbe Yes.